# Determining direction from an inductive joystick

Tags: microcontroller, inductive

I'm trying to understand and (eventually) repurpose an old inductive joystick, but I'm not sure how the micro controller determines which direction the stick was pushed in?

[image: Joystick on pcb]

There are 4 coils on the PCB and one on the joystick. The pcb coils are paired together by axis with an ADC input connected at either end, while the joystick coil is controlled by a timer output. The MCU is an atmega8 running at 8MHz.
Experimentally driving the joystick coil at 20kHz, 5kHz, and 2.5kHz seems to work. It then looks like the pcb coils oppose each other normally, so when the joystick moves towards one the amplitude from that coil increases while the other decreases.

My guess was that I could pick the direction by checking the phase, but doing so seems nontrivial with the existing MCU (slow!) and I'm not sure how to figure the phase change out from the two sets of ADC results. Is there another way that I am missing, or some trick to make this feasible?

The joystick coil is hooked up roughly like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMpZjH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remaining 4 coils are grouped by axis. The last pin of the transistor doesn't appear to be connected so I'm assuming it is acting as a diode?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLypp.png)</sup>

I have a basic multimeter and can log ADC results and push them through the serial port on the board. Below is a example waveform collected from the MCU, split into 100-sample chunks. The smaller oscillations I think is from driving the joystick coil at roughly 2.5kHz, while the large amplitude apparently higher frequency oscillations appeared when moving the joystick up or down.

[image: Y-axis data sample]

Comment: How reliable is the schematic you have given? You said there is a coil on the joystick? Not just a piece of iron? So the joystick is supposed to induce a current into the coils? If that's the case then the current in a coil should increase as the joystick moves closer to it. Or at least become unbalanced between two coils for the same axis.

Comment: The black plastic structure in the photo normally mounts roughly over the 4 inductors, there are two mounting holes. The coil in the joystick is connected to the yellow+red wires, there may be some iron inside but it is hard to tell.

Comment: @DKNguyen the schematics are my best guess from the traces and poking around with a multimeter, most of the nearby components are accounted for. The imbalance in current seems to be what I see, but it is oscillating (at 20kHz?) so I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: I think you'll find that it's basically a two-axis implementation of an [LVDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_variable_differential_transformer).

Comment: Thanks @DaveTweed - I couldn't find much literature for inductive joysticks but there is heaps for LVDT, hopefully that gives me some ideas for the data processing side of things

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on LVDTs confirmed that the phase shift (+ or - 90 degrees) should give the direction.

However the existing MCU appears to be too slow to find peaks at 20kHz by repeated sampling. Instead the solution was to run the main coil using OCR1A and trigger a sample using OCR1B, where OCR1B < OCR1A; because the generated waveform in the pcb coils is also at 20kHz we can use OCR1B to pick a phase offset to retrieve.